# Is there a way to automatically set the CreatedDate/LastModifiedDate column in EF?

Tags: entity-framework

Every table in my database has a CreatedDate and LastModifiedDate column. Is there a way in EF to automatically set those columns during INSERT and UPDATE operations respectively?

I am trying to avoid having people try to remember to manually set them in application code, as that's error prone. (And no, I don't want to put triggers on every table.)

Comment: are you using code first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `CreatedDate` and `LastModifiedDate` in every table, then probably you have some *abstract* `BaseModel` which has these two properties. Then you can override `SaveChanges` method inside your context and set these properties:

```
private void SetOperationDates()
{
    // Get added entries
    IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> addedEntryCollection = Context
        .ObjectContext
        .ObjectStateManager
        .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
        .Where(m => m != null && m.Entity != null);

    // Get modified entries
    IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> modifiedEntryCollection = Context
        .ObjectContext
        .ObjectStateManager
        .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified)
        .Where(m => m != null && m.Entity != null);

    // Set CreatedDate of added entries
    foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in addedEntryCollection)
    {                
        BaseModel addedEntity = entry.Entity as BaseModel;
        if (addedEntity != null)
            addedEntity.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    // Set LastModifiedDate of modified entries
    foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in modifiedEntryCollection)
    {
        BaseModel modifiedEntity = entry.Entity as BaseModel;
        if (modifiedEntity != null)
            modifiedEntity.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public override int SaveChanges()
{
    SetOperationDates();

    return SaveChanges();
}
```

**Note**: You can also add overload version of `SaveChanges` method whith `bool` parameter in case you do not want to call `SetOperationDates`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Generic Repository pattern , there is a simple solution . 
You can use below code for Add entity

```
 public T Add(T entity)
    {
        typeof(T).GetField("CreatedDate").SetValue(entity, DateTime.Now);
        return this.DbSet.Add(entity);
    }
```

and update entity like below

```
  public virtual void Edit(T entity)
    {
        typeof(T).GetField("LastModifiedDate").SetValue(entity, DateTime.Now);
        this.Context.Edit(entity);
    }
```